# Is there a name for this operation of collecting the translation of a point in several directions?

Tags: geometry, rigid-transformation

I am writing some code that deals with a 2-dimensional grid and have an operation I am calling `project` which takes a point and translates it by the grid unit in each direction. Is there a more descriptive name for this sort of operation -- collecting the results of translating a point and applying *n* rotations? Or perhaps a name for applying the process once (translate + rotate)?

Comment: Use your own name if no one has done this before.

Comment: Are the rotations all occurring around the origin? Applying $n$ rotations is the same as applying a single composite rotation, in that case.

Comment: @rschwieb okay, "composed rotations" is not bad. The idea is that we're gathering all the images of the vector after a few regular transformations (translation, rotation)

Comment: @JosephWeissman I wasn't suggesting that as a name, I'm asking for clarification, I guess. How many of each transformation, and in what mixture are you suggesting to apply transformations to the point? Are the rotations centered on the origin?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, the set of all possible images of a selected point $x\in X$ after being acted on by elements of $G$ is called *the orbit of $x$.*

I'm not totally sure this is also applied to a set of transformations acting on a set, but you could call it "the orbit of $x$ under this set of transformations" and that would be pretty natural.

Comment: This actually captures it really well. I realized its also just picking out a "local neighborhood" of sorts and may use this language too